# How to make a list of all duplicate strings in another list with LINQ

Tags: c#, string, linq, list, delimiter

I've found a few similar topics but not one that suited my needs. I have a list of strings that looks like this:

```
List<List<string>> myList = {Foo, Foo, Bar, UniqueValue, Bar}
```

I want to use Linq to make a `List<List<string>>` that gives me 3 lists that each contain the unique values in my above list. Something like this:

```
List<List<string>> Entries =
{
List<List<string>> EntriesNamedFoo = {Foo, Foo, Foo}

List<List<string>> EntriesNamedBar = {Bar, Bar}

List<List<string>> EntriesNamedUniqueValue = {UniqueValue}
}

    //Any given list would look like this:

UniqueValue = {AccountNumber, InvoiceDate, ProfessionalJargon, SomethingElseINeed}

    //So I want to sort my lists by into groups that have the same value at list[0].
```

In my code, I have a delimited file with accounts. For each client, I want to produce a report, so I want to group the accounts by the Client ID. I produced the PDFs individually, and I want to merge the files that share the same Client ID into one file.

I could do this without LINQ, but I'm really interested in how this would be done with LINQ.

Lastly, I'd want to be able to quickly determine the number of unique items.

In Linq, you can count the number of unique values like this:

```
items.Select(i => i.Value).Distinct().Count();
```

But my problem is that my "items" are actually a 2D array. I have 50 rows and 10 columns. I want to peek into each row (at its first element) and count the number of unique values at that location.

Any tips you guys have would be awesome, thanks!

Comment: Please use real code. It is hard to understand your question.

Comment: Sorry about that. I'll keep that in mind for next time.

Comment: List<string> myList = new List<string>() {"Foo", "Foo", "Bar", "UniqueValue", "Bar"};

            List<List<string>> output = myList.GroupBy(x => x).Select(x => x.ToList()).ToList();

Comment: @JonathanMartin You don't need to keep it in mind "for next time", you need to edit your post *this time*, otherwise people are having a hard time helping you. It appears that `foo`, `bar`, `UniqueValue` are `List`'s, but people are assuming they are strings. Click the `edit` button and fix the question if you want meaningful answers.

Comment: You don't want to find/eliminate duplicates, you want to group and merge accounts (PDFs), None of this asks for a `List<List<>>` of anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your question:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string> { "Foo", "Foo", "Bar", "UniqueValue", "Bar" };

var listGrouped = myList.GroupBy(  x => x,   //the element you want to group by
                                     (key,    //the element you grouped by
                                     element  //the new list of strings grouped 
                                     )=> new 
                                     {
                                         Key =  key,
                                         Count = element.Count()
                                     });

foreach (var item in listGrouped)
{
    Console.WriteLine("- - - - - - - -");
    Console.WriteLine(item.Key);
    Console.WriteLine(item.Count);
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

It gives you this result:

```
- - - - - - - -
Foo
2
- - - - - - - -
Bar
2
- - - - - - - -
UniqueValue
1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [GroupBy method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
var grouped = original.GroupBy(s => s)
                      .Select(grp => grp.ToList())
                      .ToList();
```

Please do note that all the `ToList` calls just to make sure you have `List<string>` everywhere as you requested, otherwise you would have `IEnumerable<string>` which depending on what you want to do could be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var distinctClientd = myListOfLists.Where(l => l.Any())
                                    .GroupBy(l => l.First())
                                    .Select( g => g.ToList());
```

Is that it? Quite honestly its hard to understand exactly what you are asking.